# Rmarkdown HTML Template produces pandoc error 61

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, pandoc

Rmarkdown seams not working as usual after installing R3.4.3:

When knitting that HTML-Template:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---  

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
````

I always get the error

> 'Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61'

[image]

When setting `self_contained: no` in the YAML-header
knitting works again

Is there anything I can do to get standalone html files ?

[image: session_info]

Comment: Do you use a custom HTML template? It seems that pandoc tries to download jQuery from your server, but cannot find it there.

Comment: @ tarleb: No, I use the standard Rmarkdown- html template which is located at that path:   

   `system.file("rmd/h/default.html", package="rmarkdown")`   

[1] "\\\\apg-gf.org/HE$/userdata/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"

Comment: @Ron I'm running into this same issue on R 3.4.4 on Windows. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had this same problem. For some reason, flexdashboard was unable to load up the logo I had listed in the YAML header. Previously this just gave a warning with no problem, but then it lead to error 61. I deleted the logo line, and everything runs normally. However the text was similar to your "could not fetch" text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I think found a solution which works after installing R 3.4.4 and RStudio 1.1.442 at my new Laptop and getting the same troubles.

What solved the problem was to create a Renviron file :

```
file.edit("~/.Renviron")
```

and setting there a local path like this `R_USER="C:/Users/my_name"`

Now knitting with `self_contained: yes` is possible without error

Comment: I could not knit to neither html nor pdf. I follow your suggestion and things are working now.

Answer (score 4):

Adding "self_contained: no" should remove the error message.

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
---
```

Source: [Error when knitting default RMarkdown file in RStudio - @UsamaFoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671982/error-when-knitting-default-rmarkdown-file-in-rstudio)

Answer (score 0):

My `.Rmd` knitted completely fine, but all of a sudden stopped knitting.

The reason was because knittr was trying to fetch a badge

```
Could not fetch https://www.r-pkg.org/badges/version/rawr
```

And so it errored.

When I visited https://www.r-pkg.org/ it was also unavailable (even in the browser).

So the solution in this case is to just wait a few moments until the website is back up and running, then try again.

UPDATE: I tried 5 minutes' later, and it succeeded.