# Does anyone know how to fix error 61 in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I started getting error 61 in RMarkdown in RStudio after updating to R 3.5,  Has anyone else had this error or could tell me how to fix it?

[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMs7j.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a mnimal reproducible example as code by editing the question? Welcome at SO BTW :-)

Comment: Does this solve the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669535/rmarkdown-html-template-produces-pandoc-error-61

Comment: @RYoda I dont know how to show you repeatable code because it is only giving me this error on a one PC when i switch to another it works fine, so i dont think you would be able to create it.

Comment: OK, I see. It would at least help if you reduce the RMarkdown code to a minimum that causes the problem on your computer and show it here. But I guess @Dason has found a quite good answer already.

Comment: @Trae Does that link provide a solution for you?

Comment: @Dason I have looked into that link but cannot get that solution to work for me.