# Knitting: Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc

**Problem**
Our End User fails to produce html files, gets this error:
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
Execution halted

**TS Performed**
We set up the proxy for a previous error message.
This previous error was:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not fetch \\HHBRUNA01.hq.corp.eurocontrol.int\alazarov$\R\win-library\3.5\rmarkdown\rmd\h\jquery\jquery.min.js
ResponseTimeout
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

For this we added "self_contained: no" to RProfile.Site>
We also tried "Self_Contained: yes" .

**Current Error Message**

```
Could not fetch http://?/UNC/server.contoso.int/username$/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = ""
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/"
  queryString          = "?/UNC/server.contoso.int/username$/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Just (Proxy {proxyHost = "pac.contoso.int", proxyPort = 9512})
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
(InvalidDestinationHost "")
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
Execution halted
```

Comment: Have you tried with most recent versions of R and (more importantly) knitr?

Comment: We are using R3.5.2

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669535/rmarkdown-html-template-produces-pandoc-error-61

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 10, with user path located on a network drive.

```
Could not fetch http://?/UNC/...
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

The solution was to run R as administrator, remove the package 'rmarkdown', and reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answer by Malte: When you do not have administrator rights you can just change the library directory towards a directory where you have full rights, C: for example. The default option is your network folder "?/UNC/server.contoso.int/username$/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html", where you have not sufficient rights and therefore R can not knit the markdown file.

In RStudio, click on Tools>Install Packages.. Under "Install to library" you can see the default option (in your case it should be "?/UNC/server.contoso.int/username$/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"). The second option here should be "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library".

To change this order, i.e. to make the "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library" folder the default folder, you have to use the following code (execute the code in a new R file) :

```
bothPaths <- .libPaths()   # extract both paths
bothPaths <- c(bothPaths [2], bothPaths [1])  # change order
.libPaths(bothPaths )  # modify the order
```

After that, you might have to install the markdown package again. This time, it will be directly installed into the "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library" folder.

Now, knitting should be working, because R will use the package straight from a folder where you have full rights.

Answer (score 0):

Aand issue was resolved. Someone changed a rule on the server hosting the files without documenting/logging....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue only when I deployed to a Shiny server probably due to a different `pandoc` version than what I had locally. This was the error I saw:

```
Could not fetch javascript:void(0)#view=Fit
InvalidUrlException "javascript:void(0)#view=Fit" "Invalid scheme"
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

The culprit was a JavaScript call in an `iframe` tag in the R Markdown document. I guess any reference to a URL that `pandoc` considers invalid might cause that.

```
<iframe name="ifrmPDF" id="ifrmPDF" src="javascript:void(0)#view=Fit"></iframe>
```

I added `data-external="1"` to the iframe attributes and it solved it.

```
<iframe name="ifrmPDF" id="ifrmPDF" src="javascript:void(0)#view=Fit" data-external="1" ></iframe>
```

Using the alternative solution `self_contained: no` also worked but the product ended up with an extra folder with dependencies of my final HTML file and I did not like that directory layout. So I used the solution above.

I have used the same technique to solve the issue of a videos not showing in an `iframe` with `src` pointing to a YouTube video link does not work after conversion to HTML in R Markdown. The same `data-external="1"` solved that issue too.

**Reference**: https://community.rstudio.com/t/insert-raw-html-iframe-into-rmarkdown/94334/6