# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61

Tags: r

I am running `create_report()` on a data frame, and R is returning an error message.

I have tried uninstalling `rmarkdown` and reinstalling after opening R as an admin. I have also tried Ron's comment here which suggests doing the following below: [Rmarkdown HTML Template produces pandoc error 61](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669535/rmarkdown-html-template-produces-pandoc-error-61)

`file.edit("~/.Renviron")` and setting there a local path like this `R_USER="C:/Users/my_name"`

I ran this:

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=******;Database=*******;trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(****,'SELECT fid****, fid****, fid**** FROM *************') WHERE fid**** = 'XXXXXXX' AND fid**** = 'XXXXXX';"))
odbcClose(dbconnection)

summary(initdata)
glimpse(initdata)
vis_miss(initdata)
vis_dat(initdata)
create_report(initdata)
```

And RStudio returns this:

```
Could not fetch http://?/UNC/******/FolderRedirection/user.name/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = ""
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/"
  queryString          = "?/UNC/******/FolderRedirection/user.name/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (InvalidDestinationHost "")
Quitting from lines 27-36 (test.Rmd) 
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
Execution halted
```

I expect to be able to produce charts in an HTML document as described at the bottom of the following page:

https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/simple-eda

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems (at least in my case) from the fact that the used markdown library is a network folder (in your case "?/UNC/******/FolderRedirection/user.name/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"). R cannot access this folder because rights are missing.

You have to change your default library to a place where you have full rights. For example "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library".

In RStudio, click on Tools>Install Packages.. Under "Install to library" you can see the default option (in your case it should be "?/UNC/******/FolderRedirection/user.name/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html"). The second option here should be "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library".

To change this order, i.e. to make the "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library" folder the default folder, you have to use the following code (execute the code in a new R file) :

```
bothPaths <- .libPaths()   # extract both paths
bothPaths <- c(bothPaths [2], bothPaths [1])  # change order
.libPaths(bothPaths )  # modify the order
```

After that, you might have to install the markdown package again. This time, it will be directly installed into the "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library" folder.

Now, knitting should be working, because R will use the package straight from a folder where you have full rights.

Comment: If you find that a nearly identical answer can answer multiple Questions, kindly mark the Questions duplicates instead of answering them all.