# Rmarkdown failed to generate github_document with latex (Error 67)

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have tried to knit several Rmarkdown files that output a github_document, e.g.:

```
---
title: 'TEST'
output:   
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: --webtex
always_allow_html: yes
---

\newcommand*{\indep}{\perp \!\!\! \perp}

$$\Bigl \{ Y_i, \; M_i \Bigr \} \indep{} \, A_i|Z_i=z $$
```

The error that I get is:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5CBigl%20%5C%7B%20Y_i%2C%20%5C%3B%20M_i%20%5CBigr%20%5C%7D%20%7B%5Cperp%20%5C%21%5C%21%5C%21%20%5Cperp%7D%7B%7D%20%5C%2C%20A_i%7CZ_i%3Dz%20
FailedConnectionException2 "latex.codecogs.com" 443 True sendBuf: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

A recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869253/avoid-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-61-for-github-document) ran into a similar issue for a github_document, but it is not the exact error code and the solution provided does not return all of the latex code, in my longer document, nor does it return a proper independent function. For example:

```
---
title: 'TEST'
output:   
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: --webtex=http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=
always_allow_html: yes
---

\newcommand*{\indep}{\perp \!\!\! \perp}

$$\Bigl \{ Y_i, \; M_i \Bigr \} \indep{} \, A_i|Z_i=z $$
```

returns this image: [new independent sign generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eiu.png)
previously, my github document could create this image (using the pandoc_args: --webtex): [old independent sign generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICAPd.png) . This is essentially the same line minus a few things, since it is screenshotted and the test file was edited for simplicity.

Last month, all files were able to return all latex code within my longer document without issue.

Some additional information that might be helpful:

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       OS X El Capitan 10.11.6     
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2020-04-13                  

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ! package     * version date       lib source        
   assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   base        * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [?] local         
   cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 P compiler      3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
   crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 P datasets    * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
   digest        0.6.19  2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 P graphics    * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
 P grDevices   * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
 P grid          3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
   gridExtra     2.3     2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   htmltools     0.4.0   2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   knitr         1.24    2019-08-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 P methods     * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
   Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   rlang         0.4.0   2019-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   rmarkdown     1.15    2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   rsconnect     0.8.15  2019-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 P stats       * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
 P tools         3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
 P utils       * 3.6.0   2019-04-26 [1] local         
   withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   xfun          0.9     2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
   yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)

[1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library

P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘1.19.2.1’
```

Due to my OS, I cannot update to the latest pandoc or RStudio.

Comment: Your first example code works fine for me

Comment: @J_F I've noticed that this example occasionally works, but most times it does not, and I get the error listed above. However, it surely does not work for me with longer markdown files that have latex in it.

Comment: This example also works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION provided by codecogs support!

```
---
title: 'TEST'
output:   
  github_document:
    pandoc_args: --webtex=https://ibm.codecogs.com/png.latex?
always_allow_html: yes
---

\newcommand*{\indep}{\perp \!\!\! \perp}

$$\Bigl \{ Y_i, \; M_i \Bigr \} \indep{} \, A_i|Z_i=z $$
```

According to the support team at codecogs they have been in the process of transitioning their equation cache, so their site has run into a lot of unexpected issues. So for me, my code would run maybe less than 5% of the time, and for other people who ran my code and said it was working, they were able to do so because the site was probably "up and running" at that time. They're currently working on resolving many of the issues and thankfully I was able to get assistance on their end for this problem.